# Zurb Foundation 4 large-3 to large-4 based on media query

Tags: zurb-foundation

i have the following situation in a project

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3"></div>
    <div class="large-3"></div>
    <div class="large-3"></div>
    <div class="large-3"></div>
</div>
```

i would like to use media query to modify to hide a div (large-3) for a certain width and let the other three to be large-4
how can i achieve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There should be a more efficient way to do that, but this is the first thing that comes to mind:

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="row design-4-columns">
    <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
</div>

<div class="row design-3-columns">
    <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
</div>
```

Your css would be something like this:

```
/* Used to alter styles for screens at least 500px wide.*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {

    .design-4-columns {
         display: none !important; 
     }

}
```